# Ошибка Undefined variable: categories

Tags: opencart, opencart2.0, ocstore

Пытаюсь вывести меню категорий на странице рубрики с помощью кода:

```
<?php
var_dump($categories);
?>
           <?php
foreach ($categories as $category):
?>
           <?php
    if ($category['children']):
?>
           <li class="nav-item <?php
        if ($category['category_id'] == $category_id)
            echo 'active';
?>">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="<?= $category['href'] ?>"><?= $category['name'] ?></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">

                    <?php
        foreach ($category['children'] as $child):
?>
                   <a class="dropdown-item <?php
            if ($child['category_id'] == $child_id)
                echo 'active';
?>" href="<?= $child['href'] ?>"><?= $child['name'] ?></a>
                    <?php
        endforeach;
?>

                </div>
            </li>
            <?php
    else:
?>
           <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?= $category['href'] ?>">
                    <?= $category['name'] ?></a>
            </li>
            <?php
    endif;
?>
           <?php
endforeach;
?>
```

И получаю:

```
<b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: categories in <b>/home/m/matrixyc/site.com/public_html/catalog/view/theme/SnowWhite/template/common/column_left.tpl</b> on line <b>4</b>NULL
            <b>Notice</b>: Undefined variable: categories in <b>/home/m/matrixyc/site.com/public_html/catalog/view/theme/SnowWhite/template/common/column_left.tpl</b> on line <b>5</b><b>Warning</b>: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/m/matrixyc/site.com/public_html/catalog/view/theme/SnowWhite/template/common/column_left.tpl</b> on line <b>5</b>
```

В хидере этот же код отрабатывает корректно.

Версия ocStore 2.3.0.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В хидере код отрабатывает потому, что контроллер header.php передает массив $categories в шаблон header.tpl
файл /catalog/controller/common/header.php

```
// Menu
        $this->load->model('catalog/category');
        $this->load->model('catalog/product');
        $data['categories'] = array();
        $categories = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories(0);
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
            if ($category['top']) {
                // Level 2
                $children_data = array();
                $children = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($category['category_id']);
                foreach ($children as $child) {
                    $filter_data = array(
                        'filter_category_id'  => $child['category_id'],
                        'filter_sub_category' => true
                    );
                    $children_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $child['name'] . ($this->config->get('config_product_count') ? ' (' . $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data) . ')' : ''),
                        'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'] . '_' . $child['category_id'])
                    );
                }
                // Level 1
                $data['categories'][] = array(
                    'name'     => $category['name'],
                    'children' => $children_data,
                    'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
                    'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
                );
            }
        }
...
return $this->load->view('common/header', $data);
```

Соответственно вам надо либо в контроллере /catalog/controller/common/column_left.php добавить нужную информацию, либо использовать стандартный модуль "Категории", который выводит дерево категорий в нужные позиции (левая, правая колонка, низ страницы, верх страницы), либо что-то еще придумать.